# PowerPoint 2010 opens link to PDF file in Notepad

Tags: notepad, pdf-reader, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

When I try to open a PDF file in a Powerpoint 2010 presentation on my laptop, I get a dialog like this:

> Opening: path/filename.pdf
>
> Some files can contain viruses or otherwise be harmful to your computer.
>       It is important to be certain that this file is from a trustworthy source.
>
> Would you like to open this file?
>
> [OK] [Cancel]

When I click on **OK**, Powerpoint opens Notepad.

On my desktop and a laptop of a friend that does not happen. What do I need do change to correct this?

Comment: Does opening a *.PDF file using Windows Explorer also attempt to open using Notepad?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your file association for .pdf is defaulting to Notepad instead of [Adobe Acrobat](http://www.adobe.com/acrobat) or similar. I would suggest Installing (or re-installing) the latest version to fix the issue.

Comment: I've done that (Adobe Reader X version 10.1.0). And it doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

On your laptop, try right clicking over a PDF, and select `Open With`, then click `Choose Default Program...`

When the Open with dialog opens, select `Adobe Acrobat` and check the checkbox `Always use the selected program to open this kind of file`.  Click `OK`.

The PDF file should open in the reader, and each time your computer tries to open a PDF, it should use the reader by default.